# Error in batch file due to space

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am having trouble with a seemingly simple script I have which essentially copies an item from the user's PC and places it on another computer; however, the destination file path contains a space in it. I have tried multiple methods of correcting this issue (some I don't completely understand) from using double quotation marks around the string to forcing it to run powershell.

To give a very brief precursor to this situation, I must add that I initially created this script using Powershell on Windows 10 and I should also add that it works completely fine in Powershell, just not as a .bat. I understand there may be some differences in the languages or what is interpreted through the programs.

Here is the string in the question:

```
Copy-Item $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\VAST.accdb -destination "\\PRECDP19670\C$\Users\WAKE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

The destination contains the space in the filepath.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `Copy-item` is a PowerShell command that can only be executed in PowerShell.

Comment: "There may be some differences in the languages" is a vast understatement. Batch scripting is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike PowerShell scripting. You have to decide if you're using PowerShell or batch files (or maybe PowerShell *from* batch files) before this question has a meaningful answer. The least burdensome way to invoke PowerShell form batch files is to put your script in its own `.ps1` file and invoke `powershell.exe -file script.ps1`. It is possible to execute commands directly, but you quickly run into quoting issues, requiring nasty workarounds like `-EncodedCommand`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you man. I actually scrapped using PowerShell and just made the script in batch and it is working great. Best of all, I thought working in batch file would have been more difficult, yet it seems to be easier than when I was writing in PowerShell.

Used a simple **xcopy** and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill mentioned, your BAT file needs to call PowerShell as an executable.

```
PowerShell.exe -command 'Copy-Item $ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop\VAST.accdb -destination "\\PRECDP19670\C$\Users\WAKE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

Comment: Better double quote the entire command and escappe inner double quotes with a backslash `\"` or exchange the inner double quotes with single ones.

Comment: Why go through all that trouble when you can simply type the `Copy-Item` command at the PowerShell prompt?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have about 200+ machines that I have to run this script for each machine in a batch of 30. So I made these little scripts for each batch of 30. I didn't really understand how to convert the PowerShell script into an exe that I could just run when needed, so I pushed it all over to a .bat in order to execute the scripts easily.

When I was using PowerShell, I was having to copy and paste the strings in there each time I wanted to execute the job.

Comment: You can use Group Policy to distribute files. This would be recommended rather than a script.